# Consecutive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first, fourth and thirteenth terms of an arithmetic series are consecutive terms in a (non-constant) geometric series. The sixth term in the arithmetic series is **78**. find the first term and the common difference of the arithmetic series?

I am not sure what is the meaning of **" The first, fourth and thirteenth terms of an arithmetic series are consecutive terms in a (non-constant) geometric series "**

Answer (score 1):

It means the following:

$$\frac{a_4}{a_1}=\frac{a_{13}}{a_4}$$

$a_4 \neq a_1$